# Entity Framework: is it possible to make object context internal?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have ObjectContext named for example MyEntities. There is also some entities, let's say they are Entity1 and Entity2. I want to make MyEntities internal. Entity1 and Entity2 must be public. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework v4 and Visual Studio 2010, then access mode can be set in design time using Entity Designer by setting the necessary value to the Entity Container Access property of the model. 
If you are using EF v1 and Visual Studio 2008, then you'll have to use external code generation mechanisms like T4 templates.